# Cordova iOS Build in Netbeans

Tags: ios, cordova, netbeans

I am building a cordova app using Netbeans 8.0. My problem is that although it builds on Xcode, I am getting the following error in Netbeans.

```
update-ios:
cordova prepare ios
build-ios-xcodebuild:
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos6.0" cannot be located.
/Users/abc123/nbproject/build.xml:178: exec returned: 64
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 0 seconds)
```

Xcode is at version 5.1. I assume I need to add the SDK path to a file somewhere, but I don't know where that is nor where to put it.

I can still use Xcode if I have to but it is quite cumbersome when the Android version still uses Netbeans. The provisioning profile is set correctly.

Comment: Which iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: iOS 6 or iOS 7. I have access to phones with both. I have tried changing in Xcode, but have had no luck.

Comment: I am stuck with this as well.  Any solution?

Comment: You need to modify the Netbeans project files in a text editor. There is a reference to iphoneos6.0 which you can change to iphoneos8.1

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans goto configure cordova.  You can find a link by clicking on the build device icon.  from the popup select mobile platform setup.  put the correct path there.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. Using Netbeans 8.0.2, Xcode 6.1.1 e IOS Simulator 8.1 (550.3)

The tip, in the commentaries, from [tl8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3562799/tl8), is great. Go to the Project Files Tab (Cmd+2 or on the menu bar, *Windows -> Files*).

On the files:

1. *YourProject/nbproject/ios.properties*
2. *YourProject/nbproject/ios_1.properties*

Inside those files you can make the changes. The first concerns to the simulator version. The second is about the ios version on the device.